# Background downloading stops in iOS 10 only using alamofire

Tags: alamofire, xcode8, ios10

If user starts downloading and take the application to the background and after a few minutes comes back to the app, the downloading automatically stops (only in iOS 10) but working fine in iOS 9 using alamofire.

Answer (score 0):

If background downloading was working fine in iOS 9 & now problem in iOS 10 only, so just need to update alamofire for swift 3.0 & enjoy